# How to fix "libtensorflow DllNotFoundException" when I already have the file?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tensorflow, tensorflowsharp

I'm new to C# and I've been researching this error for a long time.

I wanted to use my trained TensorFlow model with Tensorflowsharp in Visual Studio for Mac so I created a .NET console project and installed TensorflowSharp 1.13.0 from nuget.org using the built-in package manager.

However, when I included the following code in `Program.cs`

```cs
using System;
using TensorFlow;

namespace ai
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var graph = new TFGraph();
        }
    }
}
```

I got this error message:

```
Unhandled Exception:
System.DllNotFoundException: libtensorflow
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) TensorFlow.TFGraph.TF_NewGraph()
  at TensorFlow.TFGraph..ctor () [0x00022] in <a8cd6d02fde04a81817b4f25d24a7be9>:0
```

According to some of the posts that I found, this might states that `libtensorflow.dylib` is not in `bin/Debug/` directory, but when I looked into it I found the file inside.

What am I doing wrong?

My environment setup:

- Mac OSX 10.14
- Visual Studio for Mac COMMUNITY 7.7.4(build 1)
- Target framework: .NET 4.7.1

Thank you so much for any help!

Comment: try removing the extension. keep the file named as `libtensorflow`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try change to 64 bit.

This may not correct answer to you. But give a try.
I dont have mac environment. But I tried woth .net core and TensorflowSharp and it works fine.
Same time I tried with .net framework and I also got dll not found issue and BadImageFormatException.

https://github.com/migueldeicaza/TensorFlowSharp/issues/103
https://github.com/migueldeicaza/TensorFlowSharp/issues/103